# StatusCode: 405, ReasonPhrase: 'Method Not Allowed', Version: 1.1, , Content: System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionResponseContent asp.net core 3.1

Tags: c#, async-await, http-post, asp.net-core-mvc, input-file

Tengo mi **appweb-resposive** desarrollado con `asp.net core 3.1` en la tengo un formulario que permite capturar fotos desde dispositivo móvil y necesito guardar esa imagen en donde esta deployada mi aplicación web (el deploy esta en `IIS 10`) al intentar guardar la imagen capturada con input type file mediante un método post para copiar en el servidor donde esta ejecutando la aplicación me muestra error.

Este es mi código:

En la vista tengo mi input

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" 
action="/Incidents/RecordIncidents"> <div>
     <input type="file" id="mypic" name="mypic" accept="image/*" capture="camera">
     <canvas id="canvas" style="width:50%; height:50%"></canvas>
     <img id="preview" src="Imagen a cargar" style="display:none" />
     <input class="btn-user" type="submit" value="GUARDAR"> </div> </form>
```

En controlador

```
public async Task<IActionResult> RecordIncidents([FromForm] IFormFile mypic) {
  if (mypic != null && mypic.Length > 0) {
    using (var client = new HttpClient()) {
      // URL del servidor remoto donde deseas guardar la imagen
      string url = "http://192.168.5.37/imagenes";

      // Convertir la imagen a datos binarios
      byte[] imageData;
      using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream()) {
        await mypic.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
        imageData = memoryStream.ToArray();
      }

      // Crear una solicitud HTTP POST y adjuntar la imagen como datos binarios
      using (var content = new MultipartFormDataContent()) {
        content.Add(new ByteArrayContent(imageData), "mypic", mypic.FileName);
        var response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);

        // Verificar la respuesta del servidor remoto
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
          // La imagen se guardó correctamente en el servidor remoto
          return RedirectToAction("Index");
        } else {
          // Ocurrió un error al guardar la imagen en el servidor remoto
          // Manejar el error según tus necesidades
          return View("Error");
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

He creado la carpeta en el servidor en la ruta C:\inetpub\wwwroot\imagenes pero al acceder a la app desde el navergado desde cualquier dispositivo me genera error y no me permite guardar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hay alguna manera de solventar este error y poder guardar una imagen desde cualquier dispositivo conectada a la web mediante el browser

Comment: Bienvenida a SOes, revisa https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour -> para que veas el funcionamiento del sitio y de paso obtengas tu primera medalla. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Te faltó agregar:

```
[HttpPost] // Esta línea
public async Task<IActionResult> RecordIncidents([FromForm] IFormFile mypic) { ... }
```

Cuando tengas que revisar una API, te sugiero utilizar la herramienta PostMan https://www.postman.com/ para que puedas comprobar en local y en el server las llamadas de las APIS con los payloads correspondientes.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150277/discussion-between-fredyfx-and-carmen-monasterio).

Comment: Pero esto me funciona estando dentro de la misma red que es el primer paso ahora me tocara crear un domino para pobrar que cualquier usuario con accedo a la app web pueda copiar en la carpeta del servidor remoto

Comment: Muchisimas gracias @fredyfx  por toda tu ayuda, atencion en mi caso, ha sido rapida y efectiva esta comucacion te lo agredezco muchisimo
Saludos

Comment: Un gusto colaborar, @CarmenMonasterio recuerda colocar el código que pudiste crear para dar la solución a tu pregunta, incluye todos los datos que justifiquen lo que modificaste, serás el héroe de más usuarios que tengan el mismo escenario. Saludos :D